# Doubt with Intervals and Inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, inequality, absolute-value

This doubt has been bothering me for ages. I would be truly grateful for any help.

> Problem 1: $\dfrac{2}{|x-4|}>1$ Express the solutions using intervals

Solution: $x\in(2,4)\cup(4,6)$

> Problem 2: $\dfrac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} >1$ Express the solutions using intervals

Solution: $x\in (-1,\infty)\cup (-5,-3)\cup (-3,-2)\Rightarrow x\in (-1,\infty)\cup (-5,-2)$

In general, let the solutions of any modulus inequality be $x\in (a,b)\cup(b,c)\cup(c,d)$ Then how do we decide when to merge two or more intervals together (as was done for the second problem) When do we $not$ merge two intervals together?
Any help and guidance would be really really appreiated.

Comment: Your *merging* process is incorrect. Plug in the value $x=-3$ and you will get an equality, contradicting the strinct inequality!
You can merge two intervals $(a,b) , (c,d)$ with $a<d$ iff $ b>c$. For example $(1,3) \cup (2,4)=(1,4)$, but $(1,2)\cup (2,4)\neq (1,4)$; whereas you can write equality if at least one of the two $2$'s is contained: e.g $(1,2]$ or $[2,4)$. You can easily see this by drawing the real line, and then coloring it where your given intervals are, and putting empy circles where "$($","$)$" are, and full circles at the "$[$","$]$" ends.

Comment: Sorry, Sir, but I couldn't understand how it was incorrect. $$\dfrac{|(-3)+3|+(-3)}{(-3)+2} >1$$

Comment: I assumed your solution to be correct, but it looks like it is not.

Comment: Sir, could you please check? I'm still getting the solution as correct.

Comment: @b00nheT For example $(1,3)\cup (2,4)=(1,4)$, Sir, could you please explain this? Sir, the first interval would mean (according to me) that $x=3$ is not to be included, whereas the second would imply that $x=3$ is to be included. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: no. $x=3$ is included in at least one of the two, so when you take the union of the two, it is contained in the interval you get at the end.
An **union** of sets corresponds to a logic **or**, whereas an **intersection** corresponds to a logic **and**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} >1$$

Assume $x\le -3$
$$\dfrac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} >1\iff\dfrac{-(x+3)+x}{x+2} >1\iff -(x+3)+x<x+2\iff-5<x$$
So the first interval is indeed $(-5,-3]$

Now let $-3\le x < -2$
$$\dfrac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} >1\iff\dfrac{+(x+3)+x}{x+2} >1\iff +(x+3)+x<x+2\iff x<-1$$
So the second interval is $[-3,-2)$

Now $x>-2$
$$\dfrac{|x+3|+x}{x+2} >1\iff\dfrac{+(x+3)+x}{x+2} >1\iff +(x+3)+x>x+2\iff x>-1$$

So $(-1,+\infty)$ is the third interval.

Putting the three together leads to:
$$S=(-5,-3]\cup [-3,-2) \cup (-1,+\infty)= (-5,-2) \cup (-1,+\infty)$$